# Mystery wall plate by front door

Tags: electrical, usa

[image]

Our neighbors have this mystery wall plate by their front door. We have the identical house (both built in 1929) and we don't have one. The fire department was there today to investigate a smoke alarm and they were apparently very puzzled by it.

It looks like a doorbell buzzer or similar above and a two-prong socket below, but the socket is smaller than modern and the blade holes are slightly canted toward each other.

Does anybody know what this is? Google image search failed me.

Comment: Try removing the plate - get the paint off the screws and test to see if anything is live.

Comment: Careful with the paint removal. Is an old house. Could very well be lead paint.

Comment: Good point. I always assume lead, although my experience has been that wall paint is much less likely to have lead than trim paint.

Comment: What country is this house in?

Comment: @shoover: USA, Washington, DC. Tag added.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This is a Despard Wall Plate with the following devices:**

[image: Wall plate]

I found an excellent website where a vintage switch enthusiast has laid it all out for us:

[image: Outlet with slants]

**Vintage Bryant and Pass & Seymour Despard Convenience Outlets with Slanted Slot**

These specialized bakelite electrical receptacles had a pair of blade slots where one was slanted or rotated in relation to the other in order to require a special plug for distinguishing the main and auxiliary contacts. These antique receptacles were often paired with pilot lights and used for electric irons or toasters for indicating they were in use. Sometimes you'll find versions of these unusual sockets with the angled slot marked GROUND and the straight slot ANTENNA; these were likely used for vintage radios. For more information see this original patent by Victor R Despard for this speciatlty outlet.

https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/despard-switches-outlets/

As the description mentions, this outlet is often paired with a Pilot Light. Only paint removal will tell, but you likely either have a pilot light or a push button on top.

[image]

I've never seen these, personally. No doubt they seem to have fallen out of favor with electricians.

Comment: Nice work. Way back I recall a few in similarly old houses, but never saw one in use.

Comment: Upon investigation, the wire may lead to an antenna somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the quick detective work! I think my neighbors are contemplating keeping a toaster by the front door from now on.

Comment: Wait, there's "a vintage switch enthusiast"??? Who knew??!?!??!

Comment: @Freeman Right? It's a distributor, but they have blogs and blurbs that make me think a hobbyist is behind it all - http://kyleswitchplates.blogspot.com/2019/02/a-guide-to-despard-switches-wall-plates.html

Comment: @FreeMan I found some old ceramic wire-nuts in my house and I deemed them worth keeping.  I'm not sure if that makes me a vintage wire-nut enthusiast or not.

Comment: LOL, Only if you start a web site, @JimmyJames!

Comment: @FreeMan There's a surprising amount of stuff that comes up on a search but no dedicated page.  I'll put it on my list of things to get to later.  I do find a lot of the things buried in the walls interesting.  It's also disabused me of the notion that stuff was made better in the past.  That's just an example of survivor bias.